# Vue.js - Unknown custom element - Using plugin in child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using the  vue-js-toggle-button plugin available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-toggle-button.

I've installed the plugin in my main.js file like so:

```
import ToggleButton from 'vue-js-toggle-button'
Vue.use(ToggleButton)
```

The plugin works fine when I use it in one of my main components, but when I use it in a child component I receive a warning:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<toggle-button>` - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.

I only receive this error when trying to use the plugin from a child component.

So for example, in my Child.vue file I might have this:

```
<toggle-button />
```

My Parent.vue file includes the child

```
<child/>
```

Anyone have an idea what's going on here?

I also want to point out that the plugin still works in the child component, but this warning is showing up in the console.  I just want to get rid of the warning.

The child file basically looks like this:

```
<template lang="html"><div>
<toggle-button id="control-toggle-pg"
                  :labels="{checked: 'PG', unchecked: 'VG'}"
                  :color="{checked: '#333', unchecked: '#999'}"
                  :value="isPG" :sync="true"></toggle-button>
</div></template>
```

Comment: I don't know that this is your particular problem, but `<toggle-button />` is invalid in Vue. You have to use `<toggle-button></toggle-button>`.

Comment: No that's not it.  I'm using it as you described, passing in props.  I just shortened it for this example.

Comment: Can you show the full child?

Comment: Sure.  I just added what the child file looks like (removed unnecessary code)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there. Hm. Can you replicate the error in a fiddle/pen/whatever?

Comment: I'm not able to install the ToggleButton plugin on jsfiddle or codepen so no I can't.

Comment: You can use [webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KonikHO88xUNDKy0CnC)  and add npm packages.

Comment: Bert, you are awesome!  Thanks so much for taking the time to help me with this.  That webpackbin you pointed me to is really nice--I was not aware of it.  When recreating the issue inside of webpackbin, I actually found my problem.  The problem was that my Vue.use(ToggleButton) came AFTER my new Vue() initialization.  When I put it where it should have been, the error went away.

Comment: @BertEvans `<toggle-button />` is not invalid if you're compiling the templates using `vue-loader`.

Comment: Glad to help :)  @DecadeMoon There are enough cases for me (>0) that its a code smell.